# Evolutions is saying my SQL has a syntax error

Tags: postgresql, playframework, syntax-error, slick, playframework-evolutions

I am using Evolutions to build a database. My `1.sql` is:

```
# User schema
# --- !Ups
create table user (
  id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  mobile BIGINT NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL
)
# --- !Downs
drop table user
```

When I start running my web app, I get this error message from Evolutions:

We got the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "user" Position: 14 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42601], while trying to run this SQL script:

I'm stumped because as far as I can tell it is syntactically OK.

(Image [here](http://imgur.com/CzIs2dZ))

(My web app is the [play-slick3-steps](http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/) app, but using PostgreSQL as the database instead of MySQL)

Comment: What is that backtick after field `id` doing? Copy/paste error?

Comment: There is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` in Postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word in Postgres. You could either escape it by using quotes (`"`s):

```
create table "user" (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  mobile BIGINT NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Or, better yet, changing its name to something that isn't a reserved word, like `users` (in plural) for example.

Comment: There is also no `AUTO_INCREMENT` in Postgres. It should be `id bigserial primary key`